# bash command to sum and print each element of a column and print a new column

Tags: bash, sed, awk, bc

Which command should I use to sum the values of two specific columns?
For example, I have the file:

```
1 4 5 1
2 3 5 2
7 8 6 3
```

And I want to sum the second and last columns, to have the following result

```
1 4 5 1 5
2 3 5 2 5
7 8 6 3 11
```

shoud I use awk and bc?
I have found many examples to sum the entire column...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
awk '{print $0, $2 + $NF }' input_file
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you tagged the question `bash` (`awk` is the most appropriate tool to use!)

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -a ARRAY
do
    echo ${ARRAY[@]} $((${ARRAY[1]}+${ARRAY[3]}))
done < input.txt
```

output:

```
$ ./sum.sh 
1 4 5 1 5
2 3 5 2 5
7 8 6 3 11
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the command to accomplish what you want to:

```
awk '{$(NF+1)=$NF+$2}1' <filename
```

Answer (score 1):

For simple calculations `awk` is the way to go. In more complicated situations you may want to parallelize the operation, you can do this with GNU parallel and a calculator of your choice.

With `bash`:

```
<infile parallel --colsep ' +' echo '{}' '$(( {2} + {4} ))
```

With `bash` and `bc`:

```
<infile parallel --colsep ' +' echo '{}' '$(bc <<< "{2} + {4}")'
```

Note, the current release of `parallel` doesn't have an easy way to refer to the last element of the input, however, a patch is in the development branch now that allows negative indexing of elements, i.e. you would then be able to use `{-1}` instead of `{4}`.